# Will undeleting an accepted answer posted by me and deleted by a moderator mark it accepted again?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, moderation

Will undeleting an accepted answer posted by me and deleted by a moderator mark it accepted again? And will I even be able to undelete it at all?

This question is related to this one: [Answer posted as a joke in an obvious manner got accepted, what do I do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291489/answer-posted-as-a-joke-in-an-obvious-manner-got-accepted-what-do-i-do)

Comment: If it's deleted by mod, you cannot undelete, although you can flag  for mod attention and ask for it to be undeleted.

Comment: And it will probably still be accepted, although iv'e never tried it.

Comment: @JonasCz mod-undeletes restore acceptance provided the OP hasn't accepted something else in the meantime. (It means if we make a mistake we can fix it quickly).